# DrawText DT_CALCRECT and SetWorldTransform

Tags: c++, windows, transform

I have the following code:

```
XFORM xForm;

SetGraphicsMode(dc, GM_ADVANCED);
SetMapMode(dc, MM_ISOTROPIC);
SetWindowExtEx(dc, 1000, 1000, nullptr);
SetViewportExtEx(dc, 1000, 1000, nullptr);

auto radians = rotation * PI / 180.0f;

xForm.eM11 = cosf(radians);
xForm.eM12 = sinf(radians);
xForm.eM21 = -xForm.eM12;
xForm.eM22 = xForm.eM11;
xForm.eDx = (FLOAT)x;
xForm.eDy = (FLOAT)y;
SetWorldTransform(dc, &xForm);

MoveToEx(dc, x - 100, y, nullptr);
LineTo(dc, x + 100, y);
MoveToEx(dc, x, y - 100, nullptr);
LineTo(dc, x, y + 100);

RECT rect;
rect.left = 0;
rect.right = 10000;
rect.top = 0;
rect.bottom = 10000;
DrawText(dc, text, -1, &rect, DT_CALCRECT);

auto width = rect.right - rect.left;
auto height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

rect.left = x - width / 2;
rect.right = rect.left + width;
rect.top = y - height / 2;
rect.bottom = rect.top + height;
DrawText(dc, text, -1, &rect, DT_TOP | DT_CENTER);
```

It's designed to draw text centered and rotated ninety degrees. The problem is the ratio of window ext to viewport ext. If they are identical, i.e. matching, then I see two lines with text correctly centered over them.

If I set the viewport to 500, 500, the lines draw fine but the text vanishes. Now I don't know what I should set the rect to before calling DrawText(...DT_CALCRECT...) but I'm guessing something large, so I tried 10000 units size, but it made no difference.

How do I get DrawText to work and scale with everything else? It's doing the right thing for the rotation just not the window/viewport ratio.

The full Visual C++ project is here: https://github.com/imekon/SampleTransform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer!

DrawText doesn't appear to work with scaled Isotropic view, but TextOut *does* work, so, where the code uses DrawText to output the text, i.e. here:

```
rect.left = x - width / 2;
rect.right = rect.left + width;
rect.top = y - height / 2;
rect.bottom = rect.top + height;
DrawText(dc, text, -1, &rect, DT_TOP | DT_CENTER);
```

replace it with:

```
TextOut(dc, x - width / 2, y - height / 2, text, _tcslen(text));
```

This does what I expected DrawText to do but draws it correctly aligned and copes with scaling of the viewport vs window.